# Wordpress Visual Form Builder $_GET

Tags: php, get, wordpress

I have a form that i built in the Wordpress Visual Form Builder Pro plugin.  I need to be able to pass variables to the form and have them displayed as the default for the field.

Specifically, i'm trying to pass a ticket number to the form:
    Ticket Number:  *

It looks like the way to do this is to use their filter vfb_field_default http://vfb.matthewmuro.com/hooks/vfb_field_default/

I've tried every URL combination that I can come up with and can't make it work, so i'm sure that i need to either change the plugin to allow for accepting the $_GET parameters, but i have no idea how.

Example:
http://domian.com/new-user-request/?vfb-5=12345

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to add into your theme function file the code...

The path to our theme is here as an example:
~/htdocs/wp-content/themes/CleanSpace/functions.php

// The 10,4 are for the plugin to work properly

```
add_filter('vfb_field_default', 'vfb_filter_field_default',10,4);

function vfb_filter_field_default($default, $field_type, $field_id, $form_id){
```

//The field_id is the vfb-5 which you can get by going to the screen options of the plugin and enable "Merge Tag", then look at your specific field.

```
        if($field_id=="5"){
                return $default = isset($_REQUEST['ticket']) ? $_REQUEST['ticket'] : $default;
        } else {
                return $default;
        }
}
```